# how to split a column values into separate columns?

Tags: linux, bash, csv, unix, split

I have a txt file, details.txt, like this:

```
name class school

a 1 sec

b 2 pri

c 3 hrsec
```

I want the values separated by space as different columns.
so column 1 should be

```
name

a

b

c
```

column 2 should be

```
class

1

2

3
```

By the end I want the file to be a .csv file.

I used

```
awk -F " " 'OFS="\t" {print $1,$2,$3 > ("output.csv")}' details.txt
```

When I open the output file in excel all the values are in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `,` (for the CSV(

```
awk -vOFS=, '{print $1,$2,$3}' details.txt > output.csv
```

and Excel would take the columns